# vba code to fetch data from website

Tags: excel, web, web-scraping, vba

I am a newbie in this website and in VBA programming as well. I am stuck into a problem where I have to fetch the data from [this page](http://www.kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345). I need to have the hyperlink url of `Check Rates 10` button. Can anyone help me with this problem.

I have done the following code:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345"
IE.Visible = False

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading
Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage
Set doc = IE.document
Dim dd As Variant
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).outerHtml
'Range("a1").Value = dd
MsgBox dd

End Sub
```

In which I am getting text of the button but I want to have the  value of the class. I think I am very close to the result but somehow cant reach to the goal...can anyone please help me...

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

(Code modified slightly from Kyle's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709911/pull-data-from-website-using-vba-excel-multiple-classname))

```
Sub Test()
'Must have the Microsoft HTML Object Library reference enabled
Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement As Object
Dim link As String

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345", False
    .Send
    oHtml.Body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

If InStr(1, oHtml.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).innerText, "Bekijk 10 prijzen") > 0 Then
    link = Mid(oHtml.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).href, 7)
    Debug.Print "http://www.kieskeurig.nl" & link
End If

End Sub
```

This code prints the URL to the immediate window. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
Sub GetData()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "http://www.kieskeurig.nl/zoeken/index.html?q=4960999543345"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading

    Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each itm In Results
        If itm.classname = "lgn" Then
            dd = itm.getAttribute("href")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

' if you wnat to click the link
    itm.Click

' otherwise
    'Range("a1").Value = dd
    MsgBox dd
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi all!am getting one more problem in this query while I am loop through the code there are some pages where "lgn" class is not available so for that I need to print "Not Available" but am getting error...

Comment: Hi, I have resolved this problem by the following code 
If oHtml.getElementsByClassName("lgn").Length > 0 Then

If InStr(1, oHtml.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).innerText, "Bekijk 10 prijzen") > 0 Then
    link = Mid(oHtml.getElementsByClassName("lgn")(0).href, 7)
    Range("f" & i).Value = "http://www.kieskeurig.nl" & link
    End If

Else
    Range("f" & i).Value = "NA"

End If


Next i
Thanks,