# Pulling up website, screenshot, and then paste on excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the process of stock prices and then verify those prices with a screenshot from Yahoo Finance and pasting in onto a excel sheet.

I have completed the first task of auto pulling adjusted closing stock prices but I need the last step of verifying said prices by automating the process of going to yahoo finance and taking a screenshot of the price that day. The script I have so far succeeds with pulling the website up on internet explorer it even takes a screen shot of the window as well and pastes it but it does it incorrectly.

> Issues:
>   1) Pastes about five screenshots when I only need one.
>   2) does not wait for the window to fully load before taking said screenshot.
>   3) I also want to just take a small part of the page.

Extra info: I am using two monitors

What I want:[image]

What happens:[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3  
'Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

Sub Screenshot()

Dim IEapp As Object
Dim WebUrl As String

'Delcaring internet explorer as web application
Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebUrl = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TWLO/history?p=TWLO"

With IEapp
            .Silent = True 'No Pop-ups
            .Visible = True 'Set InternetExplorer to Visible
            .Navigate WebUrl 'Load web page



           Do While .busy
               DoEvents
            keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Loop



 End With


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using `snapshot` inside do while loop it will perform action until its ready state is complete

```
   While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

you have mentioned need to get `small part of page` please explain further

Comment: So know it doesn't screenshot & paste five times but once (thank you) but it's still not waiting for it to load?

Comment: Will do. I need the table section that shows the adjusted closing price. Is there VBA syntax to scroll down?

Comment: Please try updated code, do you really want to get screen shot of web page or you want to extract data to excel

Comment: Updated. Still pasting the same unloaded blank window.

Comment: I need both. The screenshot is for verification.

Comment: Tested its working fine here, also in order to extract info you have to refer web page HTML elements and call it using VBA. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751880/vba-code-to-fetch-data-from-website]

Comment: Okay it works now in terms of loading the page. Extract info?

Comment: Note: `Do While...Loop` supersedes `While...Wend`. There's no reason to use `While...Wend`. `Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4 : DoEvents : Loop` is perfectly equivalent.

Comment: If you are pulling in the stock price, it is what it is.  Why do you need to verify it?  It's not like you will pull 15 from the website and when you look at it is is 14, or whatever.  The result is deterministic.