# Excel VBA: difference between declaring a generic object versus specifying object type

Tags: vba, excel

I found an unexpected (at least for me) behavior using a variable declared as `Object` in Excel-vba. 
I was trying to extract some data from an html page and so I was using a routine like this:

```
sub Test

Dim htmlPage As htmlDocument
'This is the interesting variable
Dim DataTable       As Object
Dim DataCollection  As Object

'Code to get the html page

Set DataTable = htmlPage.getElementById("a name")
Set DataCollection = DataTable.getElementsByClassName("another name")

' Code to use DataCollection

end Sub
```

If I try to run this code on the line `Set DataCollection = DataTable.getElementsByClassName("another name")` I get the error

*Run-time error '438'*

*Object doesn't support this property or method*

After the first `Set` command the `DataTable` variable has become of type `Object/HTMLDivElement` so in principle it should have the method `getElementsByClassName`.

What I do not understand is that if I declare the variable from the beginning as `HTMLDivElement` (without changing anything else in the cose) such as:

```
Dim DataTable       As HTMLDivElement
```

the above code runs correctly without errors. In that case the `DataTable` variable is of type `HTMLDivElement/HTMLDivElement`.

What is the difference in declaring a variable as generic `Object` vs specifying its type from the beginning? And why the first version of the code does not work?

Comment: `ResultTable` is not define in what you posted... Do you meant to use `DataTable`?

Comment: @R3uK yes sorry, I edited

Comment: Ok; so if you want some info on this, it is called `Late Binding` and `Early Binding`! ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580/what-is-the-difference-between-early-and-late-binding

Comment: Declaring `DataTable` as `Object` shouldn't prevent you from calling `getElementsByClassName` once you've set that to a div element on the page.  Have you tried reproducing that?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, this is why I asked the question. I ran the code on the  same element of the same page: if  `DataTable` is  `Object` i get the error, if it is  `HTMLDivElement` it works fine

Comment: @R3uK ok so the first code should be an example of `Late Binding` but why I cannot call the `getElementsByClassName` with `Late Binding` ?

Comment: Same result here - have not seen this before.  Searching around other related posts someone mentioned it being a known issue but didn't include any reference...

Comment: See Kyle's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709911/pull-data-from-website-using-vba-excel-multiple-classname

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks. At least now I know that it is not "standard" behavior but that I should expect this for "html" related cases :)

Comment: I think that "getElementsByClassName" was introduced in the "IHTMLElement6" interface so I'd be interested to see whether: `TypeOf DataTable Is IHTMLElement6` returned True or False in each type of binding and also what was returned by `TypeOf DataTable Is IHTMLElement` in each case. The reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" will need to be kept as otherwise you will get an error about "User-defined type not defined" when making these tests

Comment: @barrowc I did your test and the result is `True` for all 4 combinations: Early/Late binding and `IHTMLElement/IHTMLElement6`

Comment: There's a possible workaround with "querySelectorAll" but I've no idea why late binding causes a problem with "getElementsByClassName". Workaround: `Set DataCollection = htmlPage.querySelectorAll(#aName .anotherName)` (find node with ID "aName" and return all descendants with class "anotherName"). The return type is slightly different but might still work for you. I've left this as a comment in case anyone can solve the original "getElementsByClassName" problem