# I got an runtime error 91 " Object variable or With block variable not set" in vb excel

Tags: excel, vba

```vbs
Sub Extractdatafromwebsite()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim Eventno As String
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Eventno = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value


ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://www.bankeauctions.com/#" & Eventno

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document
On Error Resume Next
output = doc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblReserverPrice" & Eventno).innerText
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = output

ie.Quit
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677107/excel-vba-difference-between-declaring-a-generic-object-versus-specifying-objec)?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually created an instance of IE yet, so there's nothing to *make visible*

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set IE = New InternetExplorer '// <~~ The bit you need

IE.Visible = True

...
```

When you **Dim**ension a variable, you are simply reserving some memory in order to place something there. Data types (such as `Integer` or `String`) do not need to be `Set` - but Internet Explorer is an `Object`

An `Object` needs to be *built* and in order to do that, the system needs some instructions - a blueprint if you will - of *how* to build that object. This is called a `Class`.

You have asked the system to reserve some memory for your IE object, but until you actually create the object and place it in that memory, there is nothing to interact with and so you receive that error.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have **declared** a variable using **Dim** but you have not **initiated** an **instance**. It's like when you're having a baby. You can name it before it's born but you can't really call it (as you call anyone) with its name until it's born (**initiated**).

```
Sub Main()

Dim Mike As baby
Set Mike = new baby
Mike.PeekaBoo
'baby laughs
End Sub

Sub Main()
Dim Mike As baby
Mike.PeekaBoo
'Returns an error as an instance of the baby class is not found
End Sub
```